Graniteshares 3x Long - how exactly do they work?
I'm attracted by the potential gains of 3x Long stocks, particularly those offered by Graniteshares, but I'm unclear how exactly the price relates to the underlying asset. Taking Tesla for example in the image below, (sorry, not sure how to get the exact results on tradingview, going by mouse crosshairs and eyes OK) 11 Oct to 4 Nov 2021, TSLA goes from ~260 to ~415 (+60%) while 3LTP, the 3x long, goes from 3967 to 14620 (+270%) - thats alot more than 180%, which I don't think is explained by slight inaccuracies of my readings? Then, going peak to 2nd peak, from 4 Nov 2021 to 5 Apr 2022, TSLA goes from 413 to 384 (-7%) while 3LTP from 14574 to 6325 (-57%). My understanding is when TSLA goes down by 7%, 3LTP should go down 21%.
Can anyone shed some light on what I obviously don't understand about how the 3x long works please? Many thanks


Leveraged ETFs seek to provide daily return that is some multiple of the underlying.  They typically do it with derivatives and must rebalance their holdings daily.
The key is the daily return which does not directly translate to the same multiple of return over longer periods.
Suppose you had a 3X ETF on the following stock:



Day
Price
Daily Return
Cumulative Return




0
100




1
110
10%
10%


2
121
10%
21%



The daily return of the 3X fund over that period would be



Day
Price
Daily Return
Cumulative Return




0
100




1
130
30%
30%


2
169
30%
69%



So when times are good, leveraged ETFs perform better than their leverage would indicate. This is what you see in the "peaks" of the Tesla 3X ETF.
But let's look at what happens in bad times:



Day
Price
Daily Return
Cumulative Return
3X Price
3X Daily Return
3X Cumulative Return




0
100


100




1
90
-10%
-10%
70
-30%
-30%


2
81
-10%
-19%
49
-30%
-51%



As you can see, it still performs better than the 3X leverage would indicate (-51% instead of -57%) because the second 30% loss is relative to a lower starting price.
Which seems good, right? But how much must the original stock recover to get back to even? 23.5% (81 * 1.235 = 100)  How much would it have to recover to get your leveraged ETF to even? 34.7% (49 * (1+0.37*3))=100
Let's look at a stock that oscillates:



Day
Price
Daily Return
Cumulative Return
3X Price
3X Daily Return
3X Cumulative Return




0
100


100




1
110
10%
10%
130
30%
-30%


2
100
-11%
0
87
-33%
-13%



So while the stock itself is flat, the leveraged ETF actually LOST 13%.
The reason these leveraged ETF do not perform as well over long periods is that the larger losses that offset normal are much harder to overcome even with the extra leverage.  Every leveraged ETF will have some warning that says that are not designed for long-term investment, and that you should be aware of this risk (without explaining in detail hat that risk is).
Put another way, when times are good, they are very good, but when times are bad, they can be catastrophic.
